# Jest - jasmine-pit - promise and timeout

Tags: jasmine, promise, jestjs

I use jest and jasmine-pit for test my code with promise, and all are wonderfull.

I update jest v0.5.0 -> v0.8.2, and I've got a problem with the same code.

this is the error message:
**timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for something to happen**

this is my code:

```
jest.autoMockOff();
var jasminePit = require('jasmine-pit');
jasminePit.install(window);

describe('Test', function() {
  pit('testA', function() {
    var myItem= new MyClass();
    console.log("first text");
    return myItem.launch().then(function() {
      console.log("second text");
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

"first text" is write in the console, "second text" is never write and I have the timeout error message.

all is good with jest 0.5.0.

Any ideas??

---

### EDIT

Hi, I use node.js v5.0.0, typescript v1.5.3. My test are launched with gulp and jest-cli with this line

```
var jestConfig = {
  scriptPreprocessor:'<rootDir>/../scripts/jtest.preprocessor.js',
  rootDir: 'sources',
  testFileExtensions: [
    "ts",
    "js",
    "tsx"
  ],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "json",
    "ts"
  ]
};
```

my jtest.preprocessor.js:

```
var ts = require('typescript');

module.exports = {
  process: function(src) {
    return ts.transpile(src, {
        module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS,
        target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES5,
        moduleResolution: ts.ModuleResolutionKind.NodeJs,
        jsx: ts.JsxEmit.React,
        experimentalDecorators: true
      });
  }
};
```

and the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('test-tip', function(done) {
  jest.runCLI({ config : jestConfig }, __dirname, function(success) {
    console.log(success);
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: `myItem.launch()` returns a promise that never resolves. You can probably reproduce this without any jasmine at all.

Comment: Tanks for your answer. The promise call resolve(), this code Worked with Jest 0.5.0. I don't understand Why myItem.launch() return a promise then call resolve with Jest 0.5 and not with Jest 0.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Please check out your version of `jest-cli` if it greater then 0.7.1 please downgrade it to 0.7.1. All should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I downgrade to 0.7.1 but I always have an error : "timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for something to happen". Can I ask you why 0.7.1 could have solved the problem ?

Comment: If I downgrade to 0.5.0 All is good. How can I test promise with jest 0.8.2 ?

Comment: Could you please share more details about your environments where you try to execute this stuff, like do you use node.js, babel and so on. I guess you use node.js so could you please share your package.json file in that case and version of Node ?